# Play on words , help needed

Tags: synonyms, puns

Consider:

> The loco-motive threw me to the ground.

I am trying to **highlight** the word **loco** in locomotive because it was out of control and crazy.

[Meaning @ Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loco)  :

> loco [ slang ] : mentally disordered : crazy ....

[Meaning @ MacMillanDictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/loco)  :

> loco [ informal ] : crazy ....

Should I write this ?

> "The LOCO-motive threw me..."

Or this

> The loco-motive...
> The loco locomotive....

Or Something else ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to simplify the question any more. Not so nice people here.

Comment: The site is not asking you to "simplify" but to "clarify". It is not clear how you connect "loco" with "out of control and crazy". It has nothing to do with nice or unnice people...

Comment: Try these : The "loco"-motive threw me & The LOCO-motive threw me & The "LOCO"-motive threw me & The loony-motive threw me & The wacko-motive threw me ! Depends on what you want to say , to whom !

Comment: You could use a different font or something like that; italics, bold, underlining, flashing text, or many other stylistic tricks; but this isn't something covered in standard English usage books, or anything for which there are widely-accepted rules. Where are you wanting to write this? Publishing a joke book? A handwritten message? A poster or other advertising copy? A website? Each will have their own possibilities.

Comment: Conflating / conjoining slang ***loco*** (crazy, uncontrolled) and ***locomotive*** just seems to me like an incredibly weak attempt at punning (already considered "the lowest form of wit" by many). I suggest you stick with the idiomatic standard ***runaway train***.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to draw attention to your pun for people who haven't noticed it? I'd probably encase the "loco" in quotation marks -

> That "loco"motive threw me to the ground!

If you read [Wikipedia's page on quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Signalling_unusual_usage), it states:

> In addition to conveying a neutral attitude and to call attention to a neologism, or slang, or special terminology (also known as jargon), quoting can also indicate words or phrases that are descriptive but unusual, colloquial, folksy, startling, humorous, metaphoric, or contain a pun: Dawkins's concept of a meme could be described as an "evolving idea".

This sounds like the usage you're looking for, to show the word contains a pun. Be careful not to overdo it, though - you're likely to get made fun of if the pun is obvious enough it doesn't need quotation marks to draw attention to it, as here: http://www.unnecessaryquotes.com/2011/02/pun-alert.html

> Oh man, we are SO CLEVER. We better put some quotation marks on these puns so people get the joke. It would sure be a tragedy if they missed it!